# How to run Chrome apps via command line?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I'm new to linux and just installed Elementary OS.
I installed Chrome and noticed that Workflowy and a bunch of other Chrome Apps are also installed, as you can see in the screenshot.
[image]
But how do I find what is the command to run a Chrome app, say, workflowy? (So that I can launch it from command line & assign a custom shortcut to it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't really know if this will work for you as I never tested it but I found this site with many chromium command line options : http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#app
You should take a look at the --app option.

> --app : Specifies that the associated value should be launched in "application" mode.
>
> --app-id: Specifies that the extension-app with the specified id should be launched according to its configuration.

Comment: At last I found the solution myself. Because chrome auto-generated an shortcut in my Windows so I learned how to use the app-id flag. The commmand turned out to be google-chrome --app-id={The app-id of the app you would like to run, which could be found in chrome://extensions}

Answer (score 9):

To find the command that runs the app:

1. Go to the Chrome Apps page (`chrome://apps`)
2. Right click an icon and create shortcut on the desktop
3. Right click an icon that appeared on the desktop and click *Properties*
4. Copy the command

Answer (score 4):

The command is as follows:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=$HOME/.config/google-chrome \
              --profile-directory=Default \
              --app-id=$APP_ID
```

Note: You will need to replace `$APP_ID` with the exact application ID (i.e. aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek) and `$HOME` with the path to your home directory. You can probably omit `--user-data-dir` and `--profile-directory` if you are using default values, but this is how Google Chome implements their launchers.

You can find the application ID a number of different ways.

- Instructions and a helpful utility are available at https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en.
- You can find the ID in the webstore URL, for example the ID for Google Docs is aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs/aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake)
- You can goto the Extensions preferences page at chrome://extensions and enable *Developer mode*. You can then view the ID for installed extensions.

Comment: I think the developer mode is the easiest. Just created a small bash script so I can launch the app with xmonad ;)