# How to start a Google Crome app from command line?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, signal

I installed [**Signal Private Messenger**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signal-private-messenger/bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk) and it's now in the list of apps at `chrome://apps`.

How can I start the app directly app from the command line?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Chrome apps via command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/700903/how-to-run-chrome-apps-via-command-line)

Comment: Installing a Chrome app in Linux creates a separate "launcher" (desktop file, similar to a Windows icon) specific for that app - that is the app can be found in the menu or with a program launcher. Isn't that the case in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is an example using the Postman chrome application.  I used the approach described above.  I first created a new tab in Chrome so I could launch the application.  But instead of launching it I right clicked and selected Create Shortcuts and then selected Desktop.  I then opened the desktop shortcut and got the command text below.  As you can see, the app-id is an internal id, so you could not just type this in yourself.  I tested it from the Windows Start commandline and it works fine.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm`.

I found this [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/3nqBVk6CS-E)

Comment: Great. Thanks. I had only tried `google-chrome --app bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk` (and similar). `google-chrome --app-id=bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk` works just fine. `--profile-directory=Default` may be omitted.

Comment: The profile argument can be omitted only in case of a single Chrome user-profile. If you have a second one, the first will be "Default" and the second "Profile 1".